# MySQL filtering with several inner joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm currently struggling to figure out a solution to a situation I'm in. I'll give you some background on the database structure:
Table '**Entities**' has columns **Ent_ID** (AI, Int), **Ent_Type** (Enum, 'Locations, Characters, Houses, Armies') and **Obj_ID** (Int).
The Obj_ID matches the ID from the relevant table. For example the '**Locations**' table has columns Obj_ID (AI, Int), **Loc_Name** (Text) and **Loc_Desc** (Text).

Characters can be in different locations depending on the date, so I have a '**TimeSensitives**' table to store these kind of things. This table has columns **TS_ID** (AI, Int), **Ent_ID** (Int), **TS_Start** (Float), **TS_End** (Float) and **TS_Content** (Text). The **Ent_ID** is which character is being some information (such as location). The Ent_ID of the location goes into **TS_Content**.

So, as you might imagine, I have many locations each with different characters there at different dates. My problem is that I want to be to search for a location that either has a name LIKE the search filter or has a character there that has a name LIKE the search filter.

Up until now I have looped through each Entity with type 'Locations' and then for each one I have looped through all characters currently there. This is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Entities 
INNER JOIN Locations 
ON Entities.Obj_ID=Locations.Obj_ID 
WHERE Entities.Ent_Type='Locations' 
    AND Loc_Name LIKE ?
```

Then for each one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TimeSensatives 
INNER JOIN Entities 
ON TimeSensatives.Ent_ID=Entities.Ent_ID 
INNER JOIN Characters 
ON Entities.Obj_ID=Characters.Obj_ID 
WHERE TS_Type='Location' 
    AND TS_Content=? 
    AND TS_Start<=? 
    AND TS_End>=?
```

So as you might have seen, this currently only takes the search filter into account when selecting places.
I would now like to implement the search filter onto the characters too but it needs to show places that don't necessarily have matching name but do have a character there with a matching name. I hope that makes sense. My current code wont select any locations without a matching name so there's no chance to search for matching character names.

Is there any way to combine this into one sql statement? Or can somebody think of a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need any more info then please ask :)
Kallum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Entities.*,
  Locations.Loc_Name as Loc_Name
FROM
  Entities
  INNER JOIN Locations ON Entities.Obj_ID=Locations.Obj_ID 
WHERE
  Entities.Ent_Type='Locations' 
  AND Loc_Name LIKE ?

UNION

SELECT
  LocEnt.*,
  Locations.Loc_Name as Loc_Name
FROM 
  TimeSensatives
  INNER JOIN Entities AS CharEnt ON TimeSensatives.Ent_ID=CharEnt.Ent_ID
  INNER JOIN Characters ON Entities.Obj_ID=Characters.Obj_ID
  INNER JOIN Entities AS LocEnt ON TS_Content.Ent_ID=LocEnt.Ent_ID
  INNER JOIN Locations ON LocEnt.Obj_ID=Locations.Obj_ID 
WHERE
  TS_Type='Location' 
  AND TS_Start<=?
  AND TS_End>=?
  AND Char_Name LIKE ?
```

will give you all needed locations plus their names

Comment: Ah, brilliant. One more thing. Is it possible to have Loc_Name in the output? It would be useful to not have to do extra sql queries just for one field.